# getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate() works but getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(index) doesn't

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragment-backstack

So I've got a main activity that hosts all of the fragments in my app. Let me just say beforehand that every time I open a new fragment, I do it like this:

```java
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(vg.getId(), new MyFragment()); //obviously MyFragment varies from usage to usage but nothing else
ft.addToBackStack("My Fragment's Name");
ft.commit();
```

`MyFragment` in this case extends `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`, which only has a method `getFragmentManager()`. It does NOT have `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

If I want to go back to a previous fragment, from the currently shown fragment I would do `getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()`. However, if I wanted to pop the backstack from the activity, I have to use `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()` or else nothing happens. This led me to assume that calling `getFragmentManager()` from a fragment returned the same reference as calling `getSupportFragmentManager()` from the activity. However, if I try to run `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(/* an int */)` from the main activity I get a NullPointerException. If I run `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()` from the main activity it always returns zero.

So why is it then that `getSupportFragmentManager()` in the main activity simultaneously works and doesn't work? Why can I use it to pop the backstack, yet I can't access the backstack itself from the main activity? I'm totally clueless. Help would be appreciated.

EDIT: This is my onBackPressed():

```java
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(defaultSoftInputMode);
    try {
        String fragmentName = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), fragmentName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // Debug to see if the correct name is being shown
    } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        // Print to console
        // It always catches an error here and I don't know why
    }
}
```

The specific method which throws the exception is `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(int index)`. Further inspection shows that this method queries an `ArrayList<BackStackRecord>` for a value, but the exception occurs because this `ArrayList` is null.

Comment: Can you include the code where you call `getBackStackEntryAt()`? `commit()` is asynchronous, so the back stack count won't be updated immediately after a `commit()`

Comment: @ianhanniballake `getBackStackEntryAt()` is called from `onBackPressed()` in the parent activity, while `commit()` is called from one fragment contained in the parent activity to navigate to the next fragment. In other words, `commit()` will take the user from Fragment A to B and when they press the back button to return from B to A, that's when `getBackStackEntryAt()` is getting called.

Comment: That's what `super.onBackPressed()` does already. Can you include your `onBackPressed()` method?

Comment: @ianhanniballake added it to the question.